# Cannot get SSIS Error Message Inserted to SQL Table

Tags: error-handling, ssis

I have some task for excel import using SSIS. I try to capture the error message from SSIS and insert it to SQL table on my DB.
I purposely not map one column to get error message (Column cannot be null)

I tried using event handler and Execute SQL Task but I cannot capture the Error Message
Here my Package
[image]

Here I am using Event Handler onError in Package
[image]

For the EST I use Expression Builder to build the query to capture the error description using **System::ErrorDescription** variables.

[image]

But after i try to run the process I do not get the error message in my SQL Custom Log Table

Is there any step I missed?

Comment: Could you please confirm that your event handler is not also throwing an error?

Comment: the event handler update the other column except the STATUS_DESCRIPTION column

Comment: What is the size of the STATUS_DESCRIPTION column?

Comment: btw, did some testing on this with a STATUS_DESCRIPTION Column of varchar(8000).  The event fires more than once, so the UPDATE statement will fire multiple times and you'll capture whatever error is last raised.  My guess is that the error event is failing, maybe because of truncation.  The Error Description is never an empty string in my testing.  Please let us know whatever other details you can provide

Comment: Hi @MarkWojciechowicz thanks for the answer and sorry for late response. I would jus substring it to the capacity of the column since its only nvarchar(1000) if i remember correctly

Comment: Please run it in debug and check if the event handler is succeeding or is throwing an error.  You might also trace the query on the sql side to see if there is anything odd there.